# Install twisted for python failed on Lion

Tags: python, xcode, macos, twisted, easy-install

I want to install twisted on my macbook.

```
System version: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
Xcode version: Version 4.3.3 (4E3002)
```

Python version:

```
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

When I run this:

```
sudo easy_install twisted
```

It failed with this:

```
Processing Twisted-12.1.0.tar.bz2

Running Twisted-12.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_installdtZ7Lk/Twisted-12.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-NUWexg

unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

...

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

But I did have gcc installed:

```
gcc --version 

i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any one can help me?

Post:
Problem resolved by this:

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
cd /usr/bin
ln gcc gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Twisted comes with OS X, so you don't need to do this; assuming that 11.0 is an acceptable version (that's what's in Lion).  Just `>>> import twisted` and go.
2. Never, ever `sudo easy_install` anything, on any platform, except, perhaps, [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  `easy_install` has no uninstall function, and it can't give you a listing of the files it installed.  `pip install` is slightly better, but best is to avoid installing anything into your global system; components of the system itself may use certain Python libraries, and installing new versions may not be completely compatible.

Comment: +1 on the "do not `easy_install`" tip, having said that, I've found a few libaries that fail to install using `pip` but work via `easy_install` (ex: `pylint`).

Comment: Hmm - Mountain Lion doesn't appear to have a version of twisted available - doesn't work for me. Symlinking gcc hasn't helped either.